# How to install a newer version of Jenkins on 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, debian

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and I need to install a version of Jenkins greater than the one provided in the [Ubuntu repositories (1.424.6)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/jenkins-cli). Specifically I at least need version 1.426 (I want to use API tokens for an external script), but I would like to have [the newest LTS version, 1.480.1](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/).

I can install version 1.424.6 just fine through the default, Canonical repositories, but when I try to install Jenkins from [their instructions](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu), I get no upstart script as expected.

How can I install and set up a newer version of Jenkins on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that instead of changing my aptitude sources, I instead was able to install everything from the defaults and merely replace my `jenkins.war` file with a newer version. So far everything seems to be okay.